# MySQL GROUP BY YEAR(), MONTH() returns dates sometimes at start of month, sometimes at end

Tags: mysql, sql, date, group-by

I have a table, Calendar, which contains one column, datefield (type Date).  It contains every date from January 1, 2013 until December 31, 2014.

I'm using a GROUP BY to group by month/year, and the expected result is to get the first date of each month for my selected range.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT 
  datefield 
FROM 
  Calendar 
WHERE
  datefield >= cast('20131001' as date)
  AND datefield <= cast('20140115' as date)
group by
YEAR(datefield),
MONTH(datefield)
```

Here are the results:

```
+----------+
|datefield |
+----------+
|2013-10-01|
+----------+
|2013-11-01|
+----------+
|2013-12-31|
+----------+
|2014-01-15|
+----------+
```

The last two results are not what I would expect:  I would expect 2013-12-01 and 2014-01-01.  If I expand the date range later into 2014, the pattern continues:  the dates are the last dates of each month, not the first, and the last date listed is the end date of my WHERE clause.

1. Why are those last two results taken from the end of the time period I'm grouping by, not the beginning?
2. How would I adjust the query to get the expected values (12-01 and 01-01)?

(Please, no suggestions that I delete the Calendar table or use another method to get the first day of each month.  While they may be helpful in a larger sense, they don't answer my question. However, suggestions on proper terms for Googling this phenomenon will be accepted, 'cause I don't know what it's called.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you select a column while grouping, it gets that column from a random row in the group. If you want a specific value, you have to say so with an aggregation function:

```
SELECT MIN(datefield) first_day_of_month
FROM Calendar
GROUP BY YEAR(datefield), MONTH(datefield)
```

Comment: Wow, how did I miss that in the documentation?

Comment: @AleExc . . . Here is the documentation that discourages use of this "feature" of MySQL (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-extensions.html).